# Access XML Elements using XElement

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

Given the XML:

```
<Foo xmlns="http://www.un.org/sanctions/1.0">
  <DateOfIssue>
    <Year>2016</Year>
    <Month>1</Month>
    <Day>16</Day>
  </DateOfIssue>
  <OtherTag>
     ...
  </OtherTag>
</Foo>
```

There must be a better way to do this.  So far I can only find this:

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("sample.xml")
Dim xml As XElement = doc.Root
Dim stuff As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xml.Elements
For Each s In stuff
    If s.Name.LocalName = "DateOfIssue" Then
        PublishDate = cdate(s.Elements().FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "Month").Value & "/" & s.Elements().FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "Day").Value & "/" & s.Elements().FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "Year").Value)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

I want to read the elements and build a date out of it.  I've tried Descendants, Elements, and the funky `s...<Year>.Value` mentioned here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384974.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Every other method I've tried returns Nothing.
I must be missing something really simple, but I can't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your actual XML has default namespace declared at the root element level :

```
xmlns="http://www.un.org/sanctions/1.0"
```

Note that descendant elements without prefix inherit ancestor's default namespace implicitly. You can use [`Imports`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384589.aspx) to map a prefix to the default namespace URI, like so :

```
Imports <xmlns:d = "http://www.un.org/sanctions/1.0">
```

And then use the prefix along with element's local name to reference element in namespace, for example :

```
Dim xml = <Foo xmlns="http://www.un.org/sanctions/1.0">
  <DateOfIssue>
      <Year>2016</Year>
      <Month>1</Month>
      <Day>16</Day>
  </DateOfIssue>
  <OtherTag>
    ...
  </OtherTag>
</Foo>

Dim dates = xml.<d:DateOfIssue>.Select(Function(x) _
                                         New Date( _
                                            Integer.Parse(x.<d:Year>.Value), _
                                            Integer.Parse(x.<d:Month>.Value), _
                                            Integer.Parse(x.<d:Day>.Value) _
                                         ) _
                                     )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  Note that to use the actual file you will need the first commented doc, and get rid of the XElement I used to test.

```
Dim doc As XElement = XElement.Load("sample.xml") //use this for testing
Dim doc As XElement = <Foo>
                          <DateOfIssue>
                          <Year>2016</Year>
                          <Month>1</Month>
                          <Day>16</Day>
                          </DateOfIssue>
                          <OtherTag>...</OtherTag>
                      </Foo>

Dim dts As String = doc.<DateOfIssue>.<Month>.Value & "/" & doc.<DateOfIssue>.<Day>.Value & "/" & doc.<DateOfIssue>.<Year>.Value
Dim PublishDate As Date = Date.Parse(dts)
```

This could have been shorter but this way you see what was done.

EDIT: what I was trying to do last night was this

```
    Dim doc As XElement = XElement.Load("https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sanctions/1.0/cons_advanced.xml") 'use this
    Dim ns As XNamespace = doc.GetDefaultNamespace()
```

The XNamespace would have told us what to put into this

```
Imports <xmlns:s="what goes here">
```

When I looked this morning I saw that har07 had beat me to it.

I tested by adding this Imports

```
Imports <xmlns:s="http://www.un.org/sanctions/1.0">
```

and then did this

```
    Dim doc As XElement = XElement.Load("https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sanctions/1.0/cons_advanced.xml") 'use this
    ' Dim ns As XNamespace = doc.GetDefaultNamespace()

    Dim dts As String = doc.<s:DateOfIssue>.<s:Month>.Value & "/" & doc.<s:DateOfIssue>.<s:Day>.Value & "/" & doc.<s:DateOfIssue>.<s:Year>.Value
    Dim PublishDate As Date = Date.Parse(dts)
```

The other thing I did was to add a XmlToSchema item to my project.  When it is added there is an option to load from web, I used https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sanctions/1.0/cons_advanced.xml  By doing that intellisense works which I find helpful.  Don't know what was going on with my internet last night, it was awful.

Comment: I see that your code works, but I still get Nothing back on mine.  The actual XML file is 3.7MB.  The structure is about the same and the For loop works.  I have tried variations in my code:  `xml.<DateOfIssue>.<Month>.Value` and `doc.<DateOfIssue>.<Month>.Value` and `s.<Year>.Value` and some other variations.  All come back with Nothing.

Comment: More:  When I print out `?xml.Elements()(0).Name.LocalName` It gives me "DateOfIssue".  `?xml.<DateOfIssue>.Value` gives Nothing.

Comment: It is hard to answer 'about the same' questions.  Edit the original post with something that is representative please.

Comment: Here is a representative XML file. [sample](https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sanctions/1.0/cons_advanced.xml)

Comment: Something to do with the namespace.  I am having problems loading it or any other page on the site.

Comment: I added this code `Dim elements = doc.Descendants()
    elements.Attributes().Where(Function(a) a.IsNamespaceDeclaration).Remove()
    For Each element In elements
     element.Name = element.Name.LocalName
    Next` to rip out the namespaces.  It seems to work now, but also seems like a hack.  I also don't know if it will work in the future if the file changes.

Comment: Thank you for the help and the added explanation!